# restassured getting a number from an xml response

Tags: xml, xpath, rest-assured

I'm using restassured 2.9.0, and testing xml is behaving differently than testing xml.  I have a server that returns xml of this form:

```
<foo-fee bar="123">
  <baz>456</baz>
</foo>
```

I want to test it using restassured.  This works:

```
    given()
        .port(8080)
    .get("/endpoint")
    .then()
    .log().body()
    .contentType(XML)
    .assertThat()
        .body(  "foo-fee.@bar", equalTo("123"),
                "foo-fee.baz",equalTo("456"),
        )
        .statusCode(200)
    ;
```

but that returns both 123 & 456 as strings.  What I really want to do is treat them as numbers so that I can do something like this (note that 123 was in quotes above, but not here):

```
        .body(  "foo-fee.@bar", equalTo(123),
                "foo-fee.baz", both(greaterThan(400)).and(lessThan(500),
        )
```

I thought that I could simply do this:

```
        .body(  "number(foo-fee.@bar)", equalTo(123),
                "number(foo-fee.baz)", both(greaterThan(400)).and(lessThan(500))
        )
```

I've tried

```
        .body(  "number(foo-fee/@bar)", equalTo(123),
                "number(foo-fee/baz)", both(greaterThan(400)).and(lessThan(500))
        )

        .body(  "foo-fee.number(@bar)", equalTo(123),
                "foo-fee.number(baz)", both(greaterThan(400)).and(lessThan(500))
        )

        .body(  "foo-fee.@bar.number", equalTo(123),
                "foo-fee.baz.number", both(greaterThan(400)).and(lessThan(500))
        )
```

and *many* others.

What am I missing?  How do I do this?  I've googled everything I can think of, and nothing's worked yet.

FWIW, when testing json numbers are returned as numbers, so I can understand the 123, but not the 456.  And I can't figure out how to convert...

Thank you all for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Use toInteger():

```
.body("foo-fee.@bar.toInteger()", equalTo(123),
      "foo-fee.baz.toInteger()", both(greaterThan(400)).and(lessThan(500))
     )
```

The documentation is here: http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath